# Swap two tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html

I want to allow users to swap locations of two tables on an html page. Ideally I want to create a user setting that would accomplish this by saying click this button to have table 1 on top or click this button to have table 2 on top or radio boxes.
How can accomplish this?

**Edit** : Data in the table is fed through angularjs functions and is dynamic. It changes based on the server messages. I am thinking it would have to do with Jquery or something in angular that accomplish this. I dont want to do ng-show by coping the code couple of times for both of the tables.

Comment: Tough to say without knowing more about how your app is built. Are the tables loading data from an array? If so, you could use a service to store the user's preference, then simply reverse the array at render time based on that setting. 

If the tables are hardcoded into the HTML, you would have to do some DOM manipulation to switch them around when this setting is changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out this question on my own and the solution seems really simple and works great!

I used jQuery functions before and after to get the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

sNot entirely sure of your question but if you could have your two tables side by side. You can use float-left and float-right classes to control their position using ng-class with some condition

```
<table ng-class="condition1: 'float-left', condition2: 'float-right'" style="width: 50%">
</table>

<table ng-class="condition1: 'float-right', condition2: 'float-left'" style="width: 50%">
</table>

<style>
.float-left {
float: left;
}

.float-right {
float: right;
}
</style>
```